VScode remote debuger exits after change to django code?
I have configured vscode to debug my django application inside a docker container. It works well, but after I change my code, the debugger exits with the following message
[error image]
The exception message:
Exception has occurred: SystemExit       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
3
  File "/mnt/gb10/work_projects/albaraka/albaraka_backend/src/manage.py", line 28, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/mnt/gb10/work_projects/albaraka/albaraka_backend/src/manage.py", line 32, in <module> (Current frame)
    main()
    ~~~~^^
SystemExit: 3

Here is my launch.json file
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python Debugger: Remote Attach",
      "type": "debugpy",
      "request": "attach",
      "connect": { "host": "0.0.0.0", "port": 8002 },
      "pathMappings": [
        { "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src", "remoteRoot": "/code" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Here is my manage.py file
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'albserver.settings')

    # Debugger
    from django.conf import settings

    if settings.DEBUG:
        if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN') or os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN'):
            import debugpy
            debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 8002))
            print('Attached!')    

    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

and docker-compose file
services:
  alb-web:
    container_name: alb-web
    build: ./src
    command: python -Xfrozen_modules=off manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/code
    ports:
      # Hp  : Cp
      - 8001:8001 # Main port
      - 8002:8002 # Debugger Port
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    networks:
      - alb_main_network

I tried to uncheck BREAKPOINTS > Uncaught Exceptions, but in this way the debugger exits silently.

If you make changes to the code, the process restarts if you run it in debug.
